# AWK command ignores adding newline ending "\n" for blank line and print in one single line

Tags: bash, awk, sed, printf

When I use the below command, it adds `\n` to all the lines but skips for a blank line.

```
awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\n",$0;}'
```

Example:
Input:

```
George Washington, 1789-1797

John Adams, 1797-1801
Thomas Jefferson, 1801-1809
```

output:

```
George Washington, 1789-1797\nJohn Adams, 1797-1801\nThomas Jefferson, 1801-1809\n
```

Expected output:
with `\n\n`

```
George Washington, 1789-1797\n\nJohn Adams, 1797-1801\nThomas Jefferson, 1801-1809\n
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NF` condition before the `printf` block is specifically **telling** awk to skip empty lines. If you don't want it to do that then just don't tell it to.

```
$ awk '{sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\n",$0}' file
George Washington, 1789-1797\n\nJohn Adams, 1797-1801\nThomas Jefferson, 1801-1809\n$
```

By the way, if the `sub()` is intended to remove DOS line endings then it should be `sub(/\r$/, "")` instead of `sub(/\r/, "")` so you only remove `\r`s that are at the end of lines.